# A simple code for insert update & delete operation in PalmOs?

Tags: javascript, cordova, webos

I am new to palmos and i want simple code or link regarding insert,update, delete & display data usind local SQLITE.

If you have phonegap example then also it ok,just need some line of code.

Thanks in andavnce.

Ajay Patel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands it looks like you have a couple options.

You can use the native stuff with mojo as [shown in this example.](http://www.webos-internals.org/wiki/Mojo_Storage_Database)

You could also use [lawnchair.](http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/)

[this](https://github.com/brianleroux/lawnchair/issues/11) says it is supported